# Spring JPA repositories with non-annotated entity classes?

Tags: spring, hibernate, repository, mapping

Is it possible to use Spring JPA repositories with non-annotated entity classes? I have an existing data layer which was created without using JPA and would like to provide some spring data repositories which work with these entities. The entities are referenced in hibernate mapping files.

So, is there any way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915045/migrating-hibernate-to-jpa-without-annotations

Comment: You could check out the link posted by ZaoTaoBao. Please do enough checking on StackOverflow for such common questions. It would help avoid duplicates. Some sort of refactoring is required even for questions not just code :-)

Comment: this question is way more general than the other. that question points directly toward XML usage as a replacement but this may also be solved somehow else, its not a duplicate!